# Sharing class static member variable in main and shared library

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, shared-libraries

I have my main application and a shared library/plugin that is loaded at runtime using QPluginLoader.

The main application initializes the global logger. The global logger is implemented as a static member variable of the logger class.

Both the main application and the plugin use the logger to log events.

However, when loading my plugin at runtime, it appears that the plugin references a different instance of the global logger.

Is there a way to make it so that the plugin references the global logger that was initialized by the main application?

Comment: Is the logger instance declared as a static variable within a public header file ? That could explain this behavior.

Comment: @ArneJ The logger instance is defined as a static private member variable of the logger class. Initialization is done through a static initialize() function, and access is achieved through a static instance() function.

Comment: Ok in that case I have nothing to go on.

Comment: You're saying the variable is a static membrr ? So the actual definition is in a cpp of that plugin ? But then how can your program compile ? Before linking at runtime it must already have resolved the relocation of that variable. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @ArneJ I believe I figured out the issue and it has to do with how my components are organized. My logger is built into a static lib. The app and plugin both use this static lib, causing it to produce separate symbols. When loading the plugin, the plugin already has its own symbol for the logger, so it doesn't use the app's instance of the logger.